# How to Properly return a Promise in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have the following code:

```
import {initConnection,IapIosSk2, setup} from "react-native-iap"

async nativeTest() : Promise<ProductStatus[]>{
 

        try { 
            let stat: Promise<ProductStatus[]> =  await (IapIosSk2).subscriptionStatus('sku')
            setup({storekitMode:'STOREKIT2_MODE'})
            initConnection()
            return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (stat) {
                    for (let data in stat){
                        console.log(data)
                    }
                    resolve(stat);
                } else {
                reject(new Error('Failed'));
                }
            });
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
```

I am using react-native-IAP library, and am getting the following error under the "stat" variable:

```
Type 'ProductStatus[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<ProductStatus[]>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]
```

I am assuming this is an error with how I'm dealing with the Promise?  Any resolution would be great, thanks.

Comment: Relevant: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> let stat: Promise<ProductStatus[]> =  await (IapIosSk2).subscriptionStatus('sku')
> ```

The whole point of `await` is that it puts the containing function to sleep until the promise is resolved and then evaluates as the resolved value of the promise.

If you want a promise there, don't use `await`. (Don't do this, the code after that line assumes you don't have a promise).

If you use `await` then you should probably be expecting `ProductStatus[]` and not `Promise<ProductStatus[]>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here the variable will type will not be Promise<ProductStatus[], Because you have fullfill the promise using the await.
So the variable stat type should be ProductStatus[],